# How to find value of TextBox inside DataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I'm facing some problems in getting the value of the `TextBox` in my `DataTemplate`.
My `ListView` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<lstProduse>`, and the `TextBlock` inside the data template is bound to the `Denumire` property of `lstProduse`. The text of the `TextBox` is typed in by hand.

What I want to achieve is to loop through all items to get the texts of `TextBox` and  `TextBlock`.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstReceta" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding lstProduse}" SelectionChanged="lstReceta_SelectionChanged">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Denumire}"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What is your goals.. if you trying to create some UI test  you need use UIAutomation framework and mark textBlock with special attributes.

Comment: @Anton My goal is to create a Recipe having a list of Ingredients. So View i have 2 List views, one with Ingredients, another is empty and 2 buttons , one for adding Ingredients to recipe list and another for deleting from. Every Ingredient added in Recipe list has it's own data template with name of ingredient and a textbox for inputing quantity , Thats  why I need both values so i can after send them into a Mysql base.

Comment: If you understand binding well enough to bind the textblock, why aren't you also binding the textbox text to another property?

Comment: @Wep4ik in such case you don't need get values from TextBoxes inside dataTemplate. You need to bind SelectedItems or SelectedItem to property in your VM.. (for example ChoosenIngredient) and than you can use it inside command or handler which will be add this ingredient to Recipe

Comment: @Andy In the end, I add a property to my Model , and in view I bound textbox to that property with twoway binding,maybe onewaytosource could be enough. However, this is not what I want to achieve in the end by adding a new property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a view model with an `ObservableCollection`. You have already bound the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to the `Denumire` property on your item type. Just create another property e.g. `Input` for the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in your item type and bind to it, too.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0" Text="{Binding Input}"/>
```

Then you can simply loop over your `lstProduse` collection in your view model, since the properties of your items are synchronized through the bindings in `TextBlock` and `TextBox`.

Comment: Your answer helps me to solve the problem, however, I did not want to add a new property to my item type.

Comment: @Wep4ik I really recommend you to use the MVVM approach with the property, because it is not easy to do this in the view with data templates and an items control. You would have to write custom view code and that is brittle, requires a lot of effort and does not offer any benefits. Binding to a property is a much more easy and robust way. If you really cannot add a property to this item type, you can also consider creating a proxy/wrapper type for it.